# Is there a good visual companion to Tanach?

Tags: history, tanach, product-recommendation, jewish-books

I'm looking for a visual companion to Tanach, i.e. maps, charts, and timelines. So when I'm learning Sefer Yehoshua, for example, I can see maps that chart the various battles and such.

Are there any good books or online resources for something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- An amazing book called *[Seder Hakorot BaTana"ch](http://www.booksefer.co.il/index.php?dir=site&page=catalog&op=item&cs=14395)* written by Eliezer Shulman, a *Tana"ch* scholar of the 20th c. has maps, charts, timelines, and genealogies with extensive and careful explanations, including multiple opinions or versions where necessary, all informed by the words of *chaza"l* as well as the modern (Bar-Ilan-type) lay scholars. It is a large format book and the text is penned in the author's own incredibly consistent handwriting. It bears *haskamos* from 3 chief rabbis as well as noted Biblical scholar Chaim Gevaryahu. It has been translated into English as well, with minor formatting editions to the text, under the title *[The Sequence of Events in the Old Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9650502688)*.
- A fun "book" I believe is called Midor L'dor that is actually a (40ft.) foldout timeline of *Tana"ch* with some colorful illustrations. It may seem juvenile but it serves as a great visual counterpart to the conceptions of timespans found in the Torah.
- *[Atlas Da'as Mikra](http://www.mosadharavkook.com/store/item2.php?id=50)* (mentioned above by @msh210) is a good atlas for reference. It may not have all the detail you are looking for when it comes to the ins and outs of *kibush ha'aretz* but it has clear maps for every occasion. (I find it a little frustrating that it gives the impression of being "missing" a lot because they don't print anything they are not really confident in the veracity of.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about *good* (which is what's sought here), but various editions of *Tanach* in translation have maps and the like, including IIRC the ArtScroll "Tanach Series", the one-volume ArtScroll *Tanach*, and the Judaica Press *Tanach* series. I'd not be at all surprised to find that *Daas Mikra* does the same, but I'm not as familiar with it.

Comment: I have the one-volume artscroll Tanach, and it does have several pages of charts and maps. I'm looking for something a lot more comprehensive. I'm looking for maps that illustrate every time something geographically significant happens. Like when there's a battle, and it talks about people going from one place to the other, I want to see it illustrated.

Comment: Daas Mikra does have a volume of maps and charts and whatnot, to accompany their Tanach series. It is titled, naturally enough, אטלס דעת מקרא.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned Joshua and Bible battles:

[*Battles of the Bible* by Chaim Herzog and Mordechai Gichon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1853672661)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I think [Carta](http://www.bible-books-maps.com/editorials/About-Carta.asp) also published a book of "Biblical Maps"

Comment: http://www.bible-books-maps.com/Bible-Atlas/ - link to the different Biblical Atlases produced by Carta

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of illustrated guides to Tanach, complete with charts and graphs, that is published by *Tevunot,* the publising house of *Michlelet Herzog* in Israel.  The books are really nice, but can be hard to obtain if you're trying to buy them from America.

Links:

- [Publisher's Website](http://www.herzog.ac.il/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1227&Itemid=1300) (Hebrew)
- [Online Store](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/mall/index.asp?Store=130&kodstore=1034) (Hebrew)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this book, [The Historical Atlas of Judaism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785827463), at someone's house and flipped through it. It had some battle maps on Tanach and the like. I didn't have time to fully explore the book, but it seems like it might fit the bill.

It does have some negative amazon reviews, though.