# Online maps of the Biblical Middle East overlaying the modern ME

Tags: product-recommendation, eretz-yisrael, estates-inheritance, geography

Are there any maps online that contain relatively reliable Biblical landmarks, cities, routes, and boundaries overlaying the modern Middle East? I'm particularly interested in the boundaries of the inherited lands and cities of the Israelite tribes.

Comment: I think the answers to this question will have what you're looking for: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8261/is-there-a-good-visual-companion-to-tanach?s=1|1.7461

Comment: @Menachem Nothing online then?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68234

Answer (score 2):

Try http://jewishhistory.huji.ac.il/links/maps.htm#biblical

Links to Many Maps...

Probobly a Martin Gilbert map could be your best bet.
Hope this helps..

Comment: Samuel Manuel, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing this link! This answer could be a great deal more helpful if you'd [edit] in links to particular maps that are directly relevant to the question at hand, along with descriptions of what they provide. I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Just trying to help. My Whitelist filter doesnt let me see the links.