# What are the Judean boundaries with regard to contemporary landmarks?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, geography, shevatim-12-tribes, real-estate, estates-inheritance

What are the halachic boundaries of Judea (the inheritance of the Israelite tribe of Judah) with regard to contemporary landmarks/cities?

Comment: What is the halachic significance of those boundaries?

Comment: @IsaacMoses If 95% of us are from Yehuda, we're all going to be splitting that piece of land. (Those lucky Zebulonites will have huge swaths of land to themselves...)

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67974