# The borders of the promised land

Tags: eretz-yisrael

Is this a correct border for what God promised Abraham in the 1st covenant?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Israel):

"This map representing biblical King David's Kingdom at the time of his death is probably close to a halachaic Greater Israel."<sup>1</sup>

[image]

According to Genesis 15:18 the second image is correct.

[image]

https://pastorbillholdridge.wordpress.com/tag/abraham-covenant/

Genesis 15:18 – On that day the LORD made a covenant with Abraham, saying, “To your descendants I have given this land— from the river of Egypt to the great River Euphrates."

Therefore, the promised land extends from the Nile all the way to Iraq.

---

1. Map created by Rusty Russell for [Bible History Online](https://www.bible-history.com/); used here per the [CC-BY 2.0 license](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Davids-kingdom.jpg).

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67974/online-maps-of-the-biblical-middle-east-overlaying-the-modern-me

Comment: also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73231/maps-of-biblical-israel-according-to-different-authorities

Comment: See a summary https://www.sefaria.org.il/sheets/10097?lang=bi

Comment: See WIKI article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Israel

Comment: Jews are forbidden to settle in Egypt according to the bible?

Comment: @user27343 Kind of... The Bible in three places (Exodus 14:13, Deuteronomy 17:16, Deuteronomy 28:68) promises that we will not go back to Egypt, which is taken as an injunction against returning there. On the other hand, many Jews actually did live there (such as Maimonides). See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2636/9682) which fleshes out the details of the prohibition. The relevant point here is that, as Joel said, Al is not necessarily correct that this prohibition is even applicable to disqualify your map.

Comment: It may not disqualify the map, but is there is a map that can outline what was promised in the two covenants?

Comment: The above map is according to the Rambam, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Which one? I added one.

Comment: I didn't realize there was no definitive answer. The fact that you just stated there isn't one is an answer in and of itself, and all I was trying to figure out. However, I disagree that there is no practical implementation. One of the founding principles of establishing the state of Israel in the Middle East and not Uganda, was G-d's promise to Abraham to settle in Israel. Policy decisions are being made in Israel based on people's interpretation of those borders, so It's perfectly reasonable to ask what those borders looked like.