# How the areas of the tribes were possibly equally valued?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, geography, shevatim-12-tribes, mattos

I base my question *solely* on the [WIKI of the division of the Land of Israel](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%98%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C) between the 9.5 tribes (the final division by Yehoshua).

[image]

I'm not a big of a geographer, but I live in Israel, and I know the country a bit, but I see no way those areas can be valued proportionally equally (compare Dan and Menashe and Ephraim, for example).

The Torah evidently prescribes to divide the land according to the relative value of the land (Num 26,54):

> לָרַב תַּרְבֶּה נַחֲלָתוֹ וְלַמְעַט תַּמְעִיט נַחֲלָתוֹ אִישׁ לְפִי פְקֻדָיו יֻתַּן נַחֲלָתוֹ׃
>
> with larger groups increase the share, with smaller groups reduce the share. Each is to be assigned its share according to its enrollment.

Rashi ibid.:

> וְ**לֹא נִתְחַלְּקָה הָאָרֶץ בְּמִדָּה, לְפִי שֶׁיֵּשׁ גְּבוּל מְשֻׁבָּח מֵחֲבֵרוֹ, אֶלָּא בְשׁוּמָא**, בֵּית כֹּר רַע כְּנֶגֶד בֵּית סְאָה טוֹב, הַכֹּל לְפִי הַדָּמִים:

Did anyone make a research on the truthfulness of this claim, because it does not seem so from the chart?

Comment: I do not have a source, but the key is to look at agricultural / livestock production value (or in the case of Dan, international trading value) rather than square kilometers.Zebulun and Yissachar's holdings look tiny but contain some of the most fertile land and have the best water access in the country. A single dunum there might be worth 20 in Beersheva.

Comment: @JoshK Menase takes 3 times the area of the same coastal type and 1/3rd of people. Your speculations are not real.

Comment: even today a 200m2 house in Ramat Gan is worth several times more than the same house in Karmiel

Comment: @JoshK Funny, That has nothing to do with the agricultural value of the land. How about Netania?

Comment: What is the map basing its boundaries on?

Comment: Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73231/maps-of-biblical-israel-according-to-different-authorities

Comment: and: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67974/online-maps-of-the-biblical-middle-east-overlaying-the-modern-me?rq=1