# Maps of Biblical Israel according to different authorities

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, tanach, eretz-yisrael, geography

After learning through Sefer Yehoshua with a variety of commentaries, I noticed that there seems to be a lot of differing opinions in how the land was divided up amongst the Shevatim and the shape of their borders. That being said, I was wondering if there exist maps according to the differing opinions of the classical commentaries on Neveiim.

In the back of the Artscroll Tanach there is such a map, but it does not seem to cite which opinion it is going by (I presume it was like Rashi).

Are there other maps in accordance to the opinion of others, such as the Malbim, Metzdos, Radak etc?

Comment: Related if not dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8261/is-there-a-good-visual-companion-to-tanach?s=0%7C0.0867

Comment: I was looking for more of the actual divisions of the borders for each shevet according to the various classical commentaries.