# A Tnach Guidebook to Israel?

Tags: history, product-recommendation, tanach, eretz-yisrael, state-of-israel

I'm looking for a guide to Eretz Yisroel of tnach. 
Most books in this genre are guides to what happened in a particular sefer, I'm looking for one that is set up like a tour book, for example in this valley dovid fought with golias and  sancheirev camped and the Romans built a town. Bonus if it has travel directions
It should bring conflicting opinion to the whereabouts of any place/happening if applicable

Comment: slightly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8261/is-there-a-good-visual-companion-to-tanach

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen it, but doesn't something like McMillan Bible Atlas do most of the job?

Comment: Also Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73231/maps-of-biblical-israel-according-to-different-authorities?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: related although not completely matching your request: http://search.artscroll.com/Books/9781422619247.html

Comment: I got it. It's very interesting, but much more of the Hashkafa than a guide book.

Comment: I think this is only borderline on topic, and the title suggests it is not at all on topic. I strongly recommend revising the title to clarify that you're not seeking services, and revising the body similarly to explicitly state that you're looking for a guide *book*.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question at the time and knew I had seen such a book but couldn't find it - today I saw it in person (at [Pomerantz](http://pomeranzbooks.com/default.asp) since I see you are from Yerushalaim) and liked it.

> **[The Bible on Location: Off the Beaten Path in Ancient and Modern
>   Israel](http://a.co/egAz0Et) takes readers to twenty-one off-the-beaten-path locations
>   in Israel where Bible stories are said to have happened. At each site
>   she sets the scene by relating the historical context of the event,
>   then follows with the biblical text itself and her own lively
>   commentary.** Captivating and complex Bible characters bring the
>   locations to life as they face social, ethical, and spiritual dilemmas
>   not unlike our own today. Baretz’s narratives draw on history,
>   archaeology, academic scholarship, and rabbinic literature for
>   interpretations that enhance the meaning of the biblical events. Each
>   story is told in the voice of Baretz as the tour guide—knowledgeable
>   yet informal and friendly. 
>   **The Bible on Location traces the
>   chronology and narrative arc of the historical books of Joshua,
>   Judges, Ruth, 1 and 2 Samuel, 1 and 2 Kings, Ezra, and Nehemiah. The
>   book begins with the Israelites’ arrival in the land of Israel
>   (following the exodus from Egypt and the forty years of wandering) and
>   continues over more than six hundred years, until the return of the
>   Jewish exiles from Babylon to their homeland.**   
>  Baretz’s
>   descriptions are accompanied by colorful maps and photographs that put
>   actual and armchair visitors in the middle of the action. Each
>   location reveals a new episode in the biblical narrative and provides
>   inspiration and commentary that will enhance visits to the various
>   sites.